# can not get customized attribute value when using ajax in select2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, jquery-select2

I am using ASP.NET

I have a dropdown using select2 and an (apicontroller) action with two parameters is called using ajax when something is selected.

The action:

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Helper(string para0, string para1, string para2) { return something;}
}
```

The html:

```
<select id="selectCase">
    <option>Select a Case</option>
    <option value="abc" data-para1="1" data-para2="2"> "abc" </option>
    <option value="def" data-para1="1" data-para2="2"> "abc" </option>
</select>
```

The js function:

```
$('#selectCase').on('select2:select', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/MyController/Helper?para0=" + $(this).val() + "&para1=" + $(this).attr("data-para1") + "&para2=" + $(this).attr("data-para1"),
```

But when it runs, only $(this).val() gets the correct value, $(this).attr("data-para1" and $(this).attr("data-para1" are both undefined. Have also tried to use $(this).data("para1"), still not working.

Thanks,

---

I actually skipped the part that I am using optgroup in the html, not sure if that makes anything different

```
<select id="selectCase">
    <option></option>
    <optgroup label="0">
        <option value="abc" data-para1="1" data-para2="2"> "abc" </option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="0">
        <option value="def" data-para1="1" data-para2="2"> "abc" </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).find('option:selected')` to get selected option and then get custom attribute which you have defined in each options .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$('#selectCase').select2({
  width: '100%',
  placeholder: "Select an Option",
  allowClear: true
});

$('#selectCase').on('select2:select', function() {
  //getting selected option and then retrieve required data
  var $select = $(this).find('option:selected');
  console.log("para0=" + $select.val() + "&para1=" + $select.attr('data-para1') + "&para2=" + $select.attr('data-para2'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="selectCase">
    <option></option>
    <optgroup label="0">
        <option value="abc" data-para1="1" data-para2="2"> "abc" </option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="0">
        <option value="def" data-para1="1" data-para2="2"> "abc" </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for the help!!! though I am still getting undefined.... but I wonder if that's actually caused by I am using optgroup which I skipped in the original problem statement, I have updated that and also tried with $(this).children('optgroup:selected').children('option:selected').attr("data-para1") and once again it doesn't work...

Comment: i have updated my answer you can use `$(this).find('option:selected')` ,check and see if that works